# Nombre de la prenda (bata) que llevan las abuelas

Tags: solicitud-de-término, ropa

Me interesaría saber el nombre de la prenda de una pieza que suelen llevar las abuelas. Algo como esto:

[image]

Yo lo llamaría "bata", y puede que sea correcto pues uno de los significados de "bata" según el Diccionario de la lengua española es el siguiente.

> [**Bata**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAPie.jpg)
>   2. f. Prenda holgada y cómoda que se usa para las tareas caseras.

De todas formas al pensar en una bata yo me imagino más bien algo así:

[image]

Es decir una prenda de vestir holgada, con mangas y abierta por delante, que se usa al levantarse y para estar por casa (significado también de la palabra según el DLE).

Por ello me preguntaba si "bata" es la palabra adecuada para referirse a esta prenda y si, independientemente de que lo sea, existen otras, y en particular alguna que no sea ambigua.

Comment: Es un vestido cómodo (no ajustado).

Comment: Yo siempre he escuchado referirse a esta prenda como "bata de casa"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo lo llamaría simplemente *vestido*. Sin más calificativos la palabra remite a esta clase de ropa (es decir, con las siguientes características: es de mujer, es de tela más o menos liviana, es de una sola pieza y más o más homogéneo en cuanto a pliegues y dobleces, es a veces estampado, habitualmente tiene mangas, cubre la espalda, tiene un escote no excesivamente pronunciado, llega hasta debajo de las rodillas). Hay otras palabras para designar vestidos pero tienen otras connotaciones o especificidades.

En la región rioplatense se le dice *[solera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YHICGnN)* a un vestido sin mangas, a veces con [breteles](http://dle.rae.es/?id=65Jr9Dc). Aunque el DRAE dice que las soleras son escotadas, no siempre es así, y también hay abuelas que las usan (cuando hace calor).

No llamaría nunca a esa clase de vestido *bata* por las razones que mencionas. En particular el significado de *bata* puede variar según el uso de cada región. En Argentina se usan *bata*, *batón*, *deshabillé*, *salida de cama*, *salida de baño* y alguna otra más para diferentes variedades de bata, todas las cuales tienen en común que uno no sale habitualmente a la calle vestido con ellas... (y el vestido de papel desechable que le hacen poner a uno en el consultorio médico también es *bata*).

Comment: Buena respuesta con excepción de "tela más o menos liviana, habitualmente tiene mangas, cubre la espalda, tiene un escote no excesivamente pronunciado, llega hasta debajo de las rodillas."  Por ejemplo, en climas fríos puede haber tela más abrigadora..

Comment: Quise decir que no era de lana o específicamente de abrigo (el vestido genérico en que pensamos es algo que, si hace frío, requiere que la mujer se ponga algo más abrigado por lo menos encima de los hombros).

Comment: Pero yo sí he visto vestidos de lana, al igual que hay trajes de lana.  Sí, estoy de acuerdo que la lana en cuestión no sería muy gruesa. // No estoy de acuerdo con lo de las mangas, la espalda, el escolte, ni las rodillas.  Pero en lo básico, apoyo tu respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

No lo pude encontrar en ninguna fuente de referencia, pero en Chile a esa prenda le decimos ***pintora***. Es una especie de vestido abotonado que se usa para hacer labores domésticas.

Creo que este nombre no te sirve en ningún otro país, y de hecho acá en Chile es una palabra que usarían solo las personas mayores.

[image: pintora]